# How can I split the result of powershell select-string command?

Tags: powershell, split, select-string

I have a command like this:

`powershell -command "Select-String -Path 'C:\Program Files\Zabbix Agent 2\zabbix_agent2.conf' -Pattern 'ServerActive'"`

Which outputs:

C:\Program Files\Zabbix Agent 2\zabbix_agent2.conf:5:ServerActive=79.240.122.98

I want to get the "79.240.122.98" part. How can I do that? I think that the best approach would be to split the string by the "=" character and then get the second item, but I did not find the way to do it.

Comment: `Select-String '(?<=ServerActive=)[\d.]+' | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }` might work

Comment: Split on equal sign works nicely : $filename = 'C:\Program Files\Zabbix Agent 2\zabbix_agent2.conf:5:ServerActive=79.240.122.98'
$ip = $filename.Split('=')[1]
$ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a .bat file?  This works for me.

```
powershell ((select-string serveractive 'c:\program files\zabbix agent 2\zabbix_agent2.conf') -split '=')[1]

79.240.122.98
```